# getting nan on added column

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

In a dataframe `rebinnedDF`, I wanted to add another column that has repeated random row values. I create that value as `repeateArray`.

```
    year2014_bin    year2015_bin    year2016_bin    year2017_bin
0   binZ            binZ             binZ           binZ
1   binZ            binZ              binZ           binZ   
repeateArray=[x for x in range (0, rebinnedDF.shape[0]/len(rebinnedDF.columns))]

repeateArray =rebinnedDF.join(pd.DataFrame (repeateArray))
```

when I do `repeateArray[0][:2]` which is the added column, I get `nan`. Should not that have valued based on the list comprehension above.

```
    year2014_bin    year2015_bin    year2016_bin    year2017_bin    0
0   binZ            binZ            binZ            binZ           nan
1   binZ            binZ            binZ            binZ           nan


4   binZ            binZ           binZ             binZ           nan
5   binZ            binZ           binZ             binZ           nan
6   binZ            binZ           binZ             binZ           nan
7   binZ            binZ           binZ             binZ          nan
8   binZ            binZ           binZ             binZ           nan
9   binZ            binZ           binZ              binZ        nan


Desired. I want `0` to be randomly repeated based on the length of the dataframe. I have 6 million rows. Number of repetition really does not matter. 

    year2014_bin    year2015_bin    year2016_bin    year2017_bin    0
0   binZ            binZ            binZ             binZ           1
1   binZ            binZ            binZ             binZ           2
2   binZ            binZ            binZ             binZ           3
3   binZ            binZ            binZ             binZ           4
4   binZ            binZ            binZ             binZ           1
.............
```

Comment: Hi John, Just added to it. Thanks

Comment: Your code gives `'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.  Are you really using Python 3?  If your code runs, please check that what you've posted here is your actual code and not a broken version of it.  Maybe the problem is your example has too few rows?  Anyway what you've posted doesn't work at all.

Comment: Sorry, it was Python 2.7.15. then how would append either of the datatypes in the dataframe which has randomly repeated values based on the length fo the column

Comment: reformatted with more data. Does this make more sense now?

Comment: So you're using Python 2.7 but you tagged the question with Python 3?  I give up.

Comment: should not be solutions be fairly similar. I am just trying to append a column based on the shape of dataframe.